# Google Maps API v3 - Zooming to city height after a place search

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there a way to adjust the zoom Depending on the item searched, say if somebody searched on my application for a city/country/location, the viewport returned will be a bit higher than the city, So all of the city will be Included.

I know if you have several places you can do fitBounds(); but what if it's only one place like a location/country/city

Is there a way of setting the zoom a bit higher than that location?

Comment: What does your code look like?  Are you using the geocoder?  The places service? Something else?

Comment: I use places something similar to the example given here

[https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox)

It would be really great if there is a way to do that without using the Google's geocoder API Since it has usage limitations

Answer (score 0):

Google's geocoder API returns the viewport coordinates of the searched object - see the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/?hl=en#GeocodingResponses) for an example. You can feed the viewport coordinates to the `fitBounds` method.

Comment: I'm doing something like  in this [code example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox) by Google, thing is I would love to do it without the Google's geocoder API Since it has usage limitations

Comment: You could use a geocoder without limitations, e.g. [MapQuest's nominatim geocoder](http://open.mapquestapi.com/nominatim/)